# Turtle graphics - screen updates with tracer not working as expected

Tags: python, recursion, event-handling, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to put in scheduled refreshes for a pong game, so the screen updates after a time interval so the paddles (which I have segmented) move in sync on the screen. What is the functional difference between these two blocks of code? I was trying to get the first one to work but wasn't able to get it to do what I wanted but after some experimenting I landed at the second one which does:

```
pongscreen.tracer(0)

def balltiming():

    pongscreen.update()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    balltiming()


balltiming()
pongscreen.listen()
pongscreen.mainloop()
```

This second one works, but functionally they seem pretty much the same in what they're doing. Why doesn't the first one work but this does?

```
pongscreen.tracer(0)

def balltiming():

    pongscreen.update()
    pongscreen.ontimer(balltiming, 300)


balltiming()
pongscreen.listen()
pongscreen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block is genuinely recursive, so it'll blow the call stack after ~1000 frames on a typical CPython implementation.

The second block isn't recursive; the initial `balltiming` function is completely cleared from the call stack after it sets an `ontimer` event. Turtle internally calls the next iteration of `balltiming` that has been registered as a callback to `ontimer` without unbounded stack growth.

If you want to use `sleep` manually, use a `while` loop rather than recursion. However, `sleep` blocks the thread and is less amenable to precise framerate control, so generally `ontimer` is used.

A consequence of the blocking recursive calls and `sleep` is that in the first code block, `pongscreen.listen()` and `pongscreen.mainloop()` won't be reached, while in the second version, both will be reached and the main thread will block at `pongscreen.mainloop()`; the typical flow for a turtle program.

Comment: So would the stack in the second be something like: balltiming -> listen() -> mainloop(), with ontimer clearing the balltiming from the stack so mainloop and listen is seen?

Comment: `ontimer` doesn't clear `balltiming` from the stack in the second version--`balltiming` clears _itself_ from the stack because `ontimer` isn't a blocking call (you can add a `print` after it to see). You can think of `ontimer` as saying "don't block the current function, but trigger a fresh call to `balltiming` in whatever milliseconds", whereas the first version says "Call `balltiming` recursively and block until it returns". But it'll never return because there's no base case, it's infinite recursion which doesn't work in Python.